# Разбить ip адрес на несколько подсетей

Tags: подсети, сеть

Требуется разбить ip адрес 192.168.1.0 на 20 подсетей с максимально возможным количеством хостов.
Вычисляю маску 2^8 – (20+2) = 256 – 32 = 224
Ip: 192.168.1.0(11000000.10101000.00000001.00000000)
Маска: 255.255.255.224(11111111.11111111.11111111.11100000)
8-5=3
2^3 = 8 – кол-во хостов в подсети
У меня получилось 20 подсетей, с диапазоном в 8 хостов
Соответственно первый адрес 192.168.1.0
Второй 192.168.1.8
Двадцатый 192.168.1.160
Это правильно? А если нет, то в чем моя ошибка?

Comment: `256/20=12.8`. Ближайшая с округлением вниз степень двойки действительно 8. Да, должно быть 8 хостов в одной подсети. Но маску вы не верно считаете, вот то что нули в маске накрывают, то и есть хосты. так что последний байт маски 11111000=248. И он дает подсети как вы и написали, 0, 8, 16, 24 ... 160. Но вообще еще в запасе остается аж 88 адресов. И тут вопрос как читать задачу, я не вижу в ней упоминаний, что все подсети должны быть одного размера, значит несколько из них можно было бы сделать больше, т.е. минимум 8 подсетей из 20 можно было бы сделать по 16 адресов

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ, не могли бы вы еще мне подсказать, а то я не совсем понимаю.
Получается, раз остается 88 адресов в запасе, их необходимо распределить в подсети, но у них ограничение 8 хостов, необходимо маску сменить для этих подсетей? Или маска может остаться такой же?

Comment: думаю самое правильное - от 0 до 31 одна подсеть на 32 адреса (маска 224), от 32 до 159 идет 8 подсетей по 16 адресов (маска 240), от 160 до 247 еще 11 подсетей по 8. И остается не занятый диапазон на 8 адресов 248-255

Comment: Спасибо огромное! =)